# Passing InputArrayOfArrays from java class to JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I have generated following method in JNI cpp file,

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_idesign_opencvmaketest_MainActivity_train
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jobjectArray images, jobjectArray labels) {
    Ptr<LBPHFaceRecognizer> model = LBPHFaceRecognizer::create();

    /** make a call to 
    *   CV_WRAP virtual void train(InputArrayOfArrays src, InputArray labels) = 0;
    **/
    model->train(images, labels);
}
```

Now I am getting

> Parameter type mismatch: Types 'const _InputArray' and 'jobjectArray'
>   are not compatible

at `images` and `labels` in `model->train(images, labels);`

So what would be the parameter type for images and labels in `MainActivity_train` method?

And also how to call this JNI method from Java class with correct parameter type?

I am new to OpenCv and JNI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jobjectArray` is not `Mat`. The `org.opencv.core.Mat` class has a `getNativeObjAddr()` method with return type `long`, which can be interpreted as a pointer to `Mat`. More on OpenCV Java API [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/), example code [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/android/tutorial-2-mixedprocessing/jni/jni_part.cpp).

The method

`CV_WRAP virtual void train(InputArrayOfArrays src, InputArray labels)`

takes a `std::vector<cv::Mat> images` as source and a `std::vector<int> lables` as lables. So as far as I know you need to pass more than one image to your `JNI` method. See sample [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/face/samples/facerec_lbph.cpp).

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_idesign_opencvmaketest_MainActivity_train
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jlong images, jlong labels) {

Mat& matImage  = *(Mat*)images; //to create one Mat image, you need an array of Mat
Mat& matLabels = *(Mat*)labels; // create a Mat from labels

/*
To pass correct parameters, you would do:

std::vector<cv::Mat> vecImages;
vecImages.push_back(matImage);

std::vector<int> vecLabels;
//put your labels to vecLabels here

model->train(vecImages,vecLabels);
*/

Ptr<LBPHFaceRecognizer> model = LBPHFaceRecognizer::create();

/** make a call to 
*   CV_WRAP virtual void train(InputArrayOfArrays src, InputArray labels) = 0;
**/
model->train(matImages, matLabels); // function requires ArrayofMats and ArrayofInts
}
```

Comment: @Gunaseelan Glad to help.

Comment: Can you look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46233947/opencv-predict-mismatches-with-all @Zindarod

Comment: can you look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280425/jni-detected-error-in-application-use-of-deleted-weak-global-reference/46280849#46280849 @Zindarod