# OpenCV 3.3.0 predict mismatches with all

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

We called predict in Java class like this.

```
int[] label = new int[1];
double[] d = new double[1];
predict(mGrey.getNativeObjAddr(), label, confidence);
Log.v(TAG, "Prediction completed, label[0]: " + label[0] + ", d[0]: " + d[0]);
```

And in JNI predict method defined like this.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_opencv.test_FaceRecognizer_predict
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jlong images1, jintArray label, jdoubleArray confidence) {
    Mat &mGr = *(Mat *) images1;
    jint *labelBody = (*env).GetIntArrayElements(label, 0);
    jdouble *confidenceBody = (*env).GetDoubleArrayElements(confidence, 0);
    int &myLabel = labelBody[0];
    double &myConfidence = confidenceBody[0];
    LOGD("Prediction started in JNI");
    model->predict(mGr, myLabel, myConfidence);
    LOGD("Prediction ended in JNI");
    (*env).ReleaseIntArrayElements(label, labelBody, 0);
    (*env).ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(confidence, confidenceBody, 0);
}
```

Here model is declared like this,

```
Ptr<LBPHFaceRecognizer> model;
```

And initiated like this.

```
model = LBPHFaceRecognizer::create();
```

I got logcat output as

```
Prediction completed, label[0]: 1, d[0]: 38.56067116659108
```

I don't know how it returns 38 % confidence level for some other person. 
Is there anything wrong in my code?

Previously I trained opencv with 10 images of one person, those images are 250X250 sizes.

This predict method predicts all members with same level of confidence.

Comment: Is this `jlong images1` one image or many images?

Comment: @Zindarod one image only friend